# Error installing xampp on windows 7

Tags: apache, xampp, runtime-error

For Screenshot

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iQnA.jpg

1. I have problem, so before I got these error i have installed xampp `v.5.6.30 / PHP 5.6.30` and i want to update to xampp `v.7.0.18 / PHP 7.0.18` and i uninstall the old version and install the latest version.
2. Before I get the error I have error on `api-ms-"...".dll` but i finished to this error with download the `.dll` files and the error(1) is show up.

I try to fix this problem so I change the port, but not take effect.
This for screenshot port list/netstat.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/doC8n.jpg

I change the `httpd.conf` port 80 to 8080, and `httpd-ssl.conf` port 443 to 4433. But didn't take effect.

So what solution to install xamp on my windows 7? Thanks in advance.

> Extra : I don't install skype on my windows

Answer (score 0):

Try checking on your 32 system file located on the windows file (C) if you have msvcr100.dll

If it is missing go to a dll.com site and download it and insert it on your system 32 file.

Another dll that might be missing is the API-MS-WIN-CRT-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL

This video explain how to fix this if this is due to a crash like in your print.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmtV1Xew9o4

I hope it helps.

Wish you the best of luck.